# tables & functions - Pythonic code

Tags: python

First, I want to note that this is a school assignment **but** I've tried to code it for a long time (for me... I'm such a bad coder). So please, don't think that I want you to do my assigments, not at all!!! I just want your help to improve this code and find what's wrong with it. Hope you didn't get te wrong impression.

The explanation about the code is at the end of this post,
here's my code:

```
class Table:

    def __init__(self,path,sep):
        try:
            f = open(path, "r")
            read_file = f.read()
            f.close()
        except:
            print "ERROR"
            return
        split_file = read_file.split["\n"]
        for i in range (len(split_file)):
            split_file[i] = split_file[i]/split(sep)
        split_file[0].remove(split_file[0][0])
        self.rows = []
        self.rows_names = []
        for row in split_file[1:-1]:
            self.rows.append(row[1:])
        for get in split_file[1:-1]:
            self.rows_names.append(get[0])
    self.cols.names = split_file[0]
    for i in range (len(self.cols_names)):
        self.cols.appens([])
    try:
        for place in self.rows:
            for i in range(len(place)):
                self.cols[i].append(place[i])
    except:
        raise ValueError

    rows_check = []
    cols_check = []
    for row in self.cols_names:
        if row in rows_check:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            rows_check.append(row)
    for cols in self.cols_name:
        if col in cols_check:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            cols_check.append(col)
    for number in self.cols[1:]:
        if number != len(self.cols[0]):
            raise ValueError
```

- I need to write a ctor (which is the function __ init__) that receives as input (in addition to self) ".txt" file name and a string sep. The ctor reads the table and save its data. Each line in the input file (again, it's a simple txt file) contains data which are separated by the string sep.
- Opening the txt file will be in a "try-except" form. In case of failure (if there's an Error by opening the file, the code in the "except" part will run and print "There's an Error".
- If there's no failure by opening the file text, then the ctor (the function) will use exception of type of ValueError if one of the next cases is true:
- There're two columns with the same name
- There're two rows same name
- There's a row that has a different number of columns than the number of columns of the first row (the number of columns in a row is the size of the list is created after the split function call).

notes:

***the txt file is a regular one... like the Microsoft notped... ".txt"... nothing special

***the txt file contain text which is form as a table.
for example:

```
Name,Gender,Age,Salary,Height
Menny,   M,    1,   1,   1
James,   J,    2,   2,   2
Sami,    S,    3,   3,   3
```

I don't know what is the problem of this code, I have some errors while running it and I would like to make this code more **pythonic** but without changing the form of "*init*".

Can someone help me please? I'm kinda lost.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: haha, I'm just not good at coding :(

Comment: What? People spend days even with assignments (proper ones.) So that's why that one hour seemed short. /chat

Comment: OK, I'm sorry for that, but that's not the main issue. I've worked untill I was stuck. Sat and thought what is the problem and how I can improve this code, and had no idea. I'm sure that here people can give me some good advices, and then I'll continue to do my work... that's it...

Comment: Repost of the same question earlier this day

Comment: @Hyperboreus
I don't want you do to my homework guys, just need help!!! Why everytime I need to note this? Just give me some tips and advices, that's my request...

Comment: Just don't delete questions and then repost them...

Comment: @Hyperboreus
I'm not deleting any of my questions, some are banning me and putting my questions "on-hold"... they thought that I was waiting someone to solve the problem, but again - no!! here's my code, I've dont it alone, but I need advices how to code better... So please, I would like if you or anybody could just help me... thanks anyway...

Comment: @Bmap I answered your quesiton, please stop reposting it.

Comment: @Hyperboreus - I'm not doing it in purpse... I think you got the wrong impression, sorry... Anyway, thanks a lot, I'm gonna go over your answers. Thanks.

Comment: `return`ing from `__init__` when you catch an exception is probably a bad idea - your object will *appear* to have been instantiated properly, when it hasn't, which could lead to cascading bugs down the track. Not to mention that [bare `except` is considered an antipattern](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except). You should probably *leave out* the try/except block from here, and put it at a higher level in your code where you can do something more sensible than just printing about the most generic error message in all existence.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a couple of things which look a bit off: brackets, function names, indentation etc.

Anyways, I'm not sure what format you want the final table to be represented in (underlying structure). Usually, in python, we use nested lists. For this reason, in the code below, the final parsed table is stored in self.nestedList.

```
class Table:

    def __init__(self,path,sep):
        try:
            f = open(path, "r")
            read_file = f.read()
            f.close()
        except:
            print "ERROR"
            return

        table = read_file.split("\n")
        for i in range (len(table)):
            table[i] = table[i].split(sep)

        if len(table) > 0:
            ## check names of columns
            for i in range(len(table[0])):
                if table[0][i] in table[0][0:i]:
                    raise ValueError
            ## check names of rows, and their lengths
            rowNamesFound = []
            for i in range(1,len(table)):
                if len(table[i]) != len(table[0]):
                    raise ValueError
                if table[i][0] in rowNamesFound:
                    raise ValueError
                rowNamesFound.append(table[i][0])

        self.nestedList = table
        print table
```

Apart from that, you might want to get rid of white spaces around the entries in your table using the strip() method for strings.

I'm a student too, I feel your pain.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understnad the part with " rowNamesFound = []". I would like to get some explaniation about it.

Comment: and Why you've wrote: "self.nestedList = table"... I don't see any difference when the code run...

Comment: The rowNamesFound list stores the names found up until the ith index. Then, we can check for every new row name if we haven't already encountered it. I wrote "self.nestedList = table" because otherwise the table just gets lost after __init__ finishes running. Presumably, you want to keep the information in your Table object afterwards (otherwise, why are you creating an object)?

Comment: Oh, ok, got it. But what if I want to count the number of cells? should I use for loop, from range(1,len(table))?

Comment: If you want to find the height of the table use len(table). Then if you want the width, use len(table[0]). The number of cells is height*width.

Comment: I know, I tried, but this is the error I get when I do this: "AttributeError: Table instance has no attribute '__len__'"

Comment: That is because you called `len` on a Table object, not on the list `table` in the `__init__` (that was what I was suggesting). For your purposes, if you want to find the number of cells after initializing the object, I recommend you make a method inside the class: 

def sizeOfTable(self):
    return len(self.nestedList)*len(self.nestedList[0])

Then you can find the number of cells of a given Table t by calling t.sizeOfTable().

Answer (score 0):

```
class Table:
    def __init__ (self, path, sep):
        try:
            with open (path, 'r') as f:
                lines = [l.strip () for l in f]
        except:
            print ('There was an error')
            return
        data = [line.split (sep) for line in lines]
        headers = data [0]
        data = data [1:]
        if len (set (headers) ) != len (headers):
            raise ValueError
        if any (len (line) != len (headers) for line in data):
            raise ValueError
        #This is the same "row name". I interpret it as "two rows whose first columns are identical"
        firstCol = [line [0] for line in data]
        if len (set (firstCol) ) != len (firstCol):
            raise ValueError
```